# Laravel group Headings by name with Vue

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel-5, vuejs2

Hey I want to group buttons under headings. In my Controller I have a Group ID and Group Name. If several groups have the same ID, and I only want the group name to appear once and all the buttons grouped under that specific group name with the ID. So what I want is that a group name must view only once with the buttons under it.

Here is the HTML:

```
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="btn-group" v-for="command in commands">
        <div v-if="command.groupID == groupId">
          <h4>@{{ command.groupName }}</h4>
        </div>

        <commands-component
                :entity-config="commandConfig(command.id, command.signature, command.arguments, command.title, command.groupID, command.groupName)">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" v-bind:value="command.title">
        </commands-component>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the Vue:

```
    methods: {

        commandConfig: function(ident, signature, arguments, title, groupId, groupName){
            $data = {

                id: { text: 'commandModal' + ident, id: null },
                modalTitle: title,
                buttons: [
                    {
                        buttonTitle: 'Run Command',
                        buttonClass: 'btn btn-success pull-right',
                        submitUrl: {
                            url: '/admin/artisan/commands/run',

                        },
                    }
                ],
                attributes: [
                {name: "message", displayName: "Are you sure you want to proceed with the command?", type: "action-text",  col: "12" },
                {name: "signature", displayName: "Command Signature", type:'text', col:"12"}
                ],
                data: {
                    signature:signature,
                }
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }
```

here is a part of the controller:

```
     public function index() {
  $users = User::all();



  $commands = [
    [
      'id' => 1,
      'signature' => 'sync:whatever',
      'arguments' =>'',
      'title' =>'Sync Whatever',
      'groupID' => 1,
      'groupName' => 'GroupOne'
    ],

    [
      'id' => 2,
      'signature' => 'send:whatever',
      'arguments' =>'users',
      'title' =>'Send Whatever',
      'groupID' => 1,
      'groupName' => 'GroupOne'
    ],

    [
      'id' => 3,
      'signature' => 'sync:something',
      'arguments' =>'',
      'title' =>'Sync Something',
      'groupID' => 2,
      'groupName' => 'GroupTwo'
    ],
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can just manipulate your data in a computed property to group it by a certain key:

```
computed: {
  groupedCommands(){
    return this.commands.reduce(function (r, a) {
      r[a.groupName] = r[a.groupName] || [];
      r[a.groupName].push(a);
      return r;
    }, Object.create(null));
  }
}
```

Then your v-for would be

```
<div v-for="(commands, groupName) in groupedCommands">
  <h4>@{{ groupName }}</h4>
  <div v-for="command in commands">
```

Took code from: [How to group array of objects by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-to-group-array-of-objects-by-key) , haven't tested it all

Comment: try changing the order of the v-for argument to `(commands, groupName)`, I think i had the key and values backwards.  Are you using Vue DevTools?  What didnt work about it?

Comment: Yes I am using Vue Devtools and I received no error whatsoever, just blank page. My component also wouldnt show under my Vue console. I also played around with the v-for